# Will echoing html in php be likely to cause errors in the html output?

Tags: php, html, email, for-loop, echo

I have a `for` loop in php that echoes out the same text over and over again and sends it to me in an email. I only use it to check if the code has been executed every day and what the result was.

Here is a short version of the code:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $max; $x++) { 

    if (strlen($var)== 9) {
            // code to send things via curl has been removed
            $thismessage = " " . $var. " some text <b>bold text</b> some text " . $var2. "<br>";
            $message = $message . $thismessage; 
    } else {
            $thismessage = "other text<br>";
            //$message = $message . $thismessage;    
           }
}
```

and then I send `$message` to my email. This php file runs every day to send a SMS to customers that have birthdays. The message that is sent to me is basically a line saying this customer (`$var`) had a birthday today and received a message (in bold) to this phone number (`$var2`).
A lot of the time, everything works fine. All of the time, the customers receive their messages, so every code is being executed. What surprises me, is the result I get in my email.

Normally I get something like this (and this is what I expect):

> *var1* some text **bold text** some text *var2*
>    *var1* some text **bold text** some text *var2*
>    *var1* some text **bold text** some text *var2*
>    *var1* some text **bold text** some text *var2*
>    *var1* some text **bold text** some text *var2*

But often I get something like this:

> *var1* some text **bold text** some text *var2*
>    *var1* some text **bold text** some text *var2*
>    *var1* some text **bold text some text *var2*
>
>    *var1* some text bold text some text *var2*
>
>    *var1* some text bold text some text *var2***

And once I got this:

> *var1* some text **bold text** some text *var2*
>    *var1* some text **bold text** some text *var2*
>    *var1* some text **bold text< /b> some text *var2*
>
>    *var1* some text bold text some text *var2*
>
>    *var1* some text bold text some text *var2***

So it seems like the `</b>` is sometimes skipped or a space added so it doesn't render as code. But when it is skipped in (say) line 3, it's also skipped in all the following lines. I am surprised that this seems to happen so randomly and since this is a `for` loop, it's the same code that is being used repeatedly so it's not that there is an error in the code (or at least I would think).

I would think php and html should act logically and the same way every time.

**My question is:**

Will echoing html in php be likely to cause errors in the html output?
Or am I just doing something wrong?

**EDIT** Here is the long version of the code

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $fjoldi; $x++) { 
    $kennitala = $complete[$x][kennitala]; 
    if (strlen($kennitala)== 9) {
        $kennitala = "0" . $kennitala;
    }
    if (substr($kennitala, 0, 4) == date("dm")) {
            $simanumer = $complete[$x][simi]; 

                $url = 'https:....';
                $url = $url . '&T=Text to send'; 
                $url = $url . '&unicode=1'; 
                $execute = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($execute, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_exec($execute);
                curl_close ($execute);

            $thismessage = " " . $kennitala . " á afmæli í dag og <b>fékk sms</b> í númer " . $simanumer . "<br>";
            echo $thismessage;
            $message = $message . $thismessage;


    } else {
        $thismessage = " " . $kennitala . " á ekki afmæli í dag og fær ekki sms í númer " . $complete[$x][simi] . "<br>";
        echo $thismessage;
        //$message = $message . $thismessage;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3 - New information**
I just noticed that the error always seems to be begin in line number 13.
Is it possible that a variable in php cannot contain html code for more than a specific number of characters?
I also noticed that usually the first variable contains 10 characters and the second one contains 7, but when one character was added to a line in the first variable, I got the < /b> error.

**EDIT 4**
I noticed my errors always come after 150 words (747 characters). I have had results with more than 150 words and everything was fine but the errors I do get are produced after the 150 words (747 characters)

Comment: so, echoing text in PHP is not problematic, so you are doing something wrong somewhere..!

Comment: If any of your variables contain HTML (even accidentally) it could mess up your desired output.

Comment: It seems like you hare having a problem with mismatched open and closing `<b>` tags.   View the source to see what's going on AND post the 'long version' of any applicable code.

Comment: I added the long version of the code. There should not be any html in the variables. They only include strings of numbers.

Comment: and the variables are not inside or next to the `<b>` tags

Comment: And the one email where I get `< /b>` is especially strange. It seems php is adding a space after the < and before the /.

Comment: Could you also post the resulting HTML source with errors?

Comment: Seems like that is consistent with @lampyridae's answer below.

Comment: Referring to how adding one character causes the problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the reason. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem could lie further down the line, with the email sending. The [PHP mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) specifies that each line on the $message argument must be no longer than 70 characters and be separated with a CRLF (\r\n). If it's not the case maybe mail() is doing it for you and sometimes an HTML tag ends up sliced in two by a CRLF.

Comment: It seems like you are on to something. While my lines are not more than 70 characters, I noticed my errors always come after 150 words (747 characters). I have had results with more than 150 words and everything was fine but the errors I do get are produced after the 150 words (747 characters)

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the solution. I don't want to try this out now, as it would send out messages to customers, but it seems logical. I'll get the results in the morning. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I am unsure if I can mark the question as solved or not, since this is my first question here. If I can, please let me know how. :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Welcome to Stackoverflow :) You mark a question as solved by accepting an answer. There should be a clickable check mark or something of the sort next to my answer.